# Phpseclib connect MYSQL server

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, mysql-error-1045, phpseclib

I want to connect to my remote MySQL server through port forwarding. Unfortunately my hosting provider don't have `php_ssh2` installed on the server so I have to work through `phpseclib` library. So far I am able to do:

1 - Connect to server using `Net_SSH2`:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('xx.xxx.xx.xx');  
 if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) {  
    exit('Login Failed');  
 }
```

If I do `echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');`, it fetches directory listing telling we are connected successfully.

if I run

2 - `echo $ssh->exec('echo "select * from table where company_id=\"15\";" | mysql');`

It triggers:

> stdin: is not a tty ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

3 - If I do `echo $ssh->exec('ssh -f -L 3307:localhost:3306 root@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx sleep 60 >> logfile');`

It runs forever resulting in no response error from the server.

I am pulling my hair out. HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?:

```
echo $ssh->exec('echo "select * from table where company_id=\"15\";" | mysql -u username -password=password database');
```

As is it's probably waiting for a password to be entered.

Comment: @peter  stdin: is not a tty
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I can't help with the Access denied but as for the "stdin: is not a tty"... try calling `$ssh->enablePTY()` before the `$ssh->exec()`